# How to retrieve extended properties for calendar event (by name)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-calendar, extended-properties

I have an Exchange calendar populated though Exchanges Web Services (EWS) `UpdateItem` SOAP calls containing:
(Example here for an integer `TTID` and a `TTSyncID` string field)

```
 <mes:UpdateItem ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone">
    <mes:ItemChanges>
       <typ:ItemChange>
          <typ:ItemId Id="%s" ChangeKey="%s" />
          <typ:Updates>
             <typ:SetItemField>
                <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TTID" PropertyType="Integer"/>
                <typ:CalendarItem>
                   <typ:ExtendedProperty>
                      <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TTID" PropertyType="Integer"/>
                      <typ:Value>10</typ:Value>
                   </typ:ExtendedProperty>
                </typ:CalendarItem>
             </typ:SetItemField>
            <typ:SetItemField>
               <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TTSyncID" PropertyType="String"/>
               <typ:CalendarItem>
                  <typ:ExtendedProperty>
                     <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="%s" PropertyType="String"/>
                     <typ:Value>SomeStringData</typ:Value>
                  </typ:ExtendedProperty>
               </typ:CalendarItem>
            </typ:SetItemField>
          </typ:Updates>
       </typ:ItemChange>
    </mes:ItemChanges>
 </mes:UpdateItem>
```

In EWS they came back in the `GetItem` SOAP requests as

```
  <ExtendedProperty>
    <ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TTID" PropertyType="Integer"/>
    <Value>10</Value>
  </ExtendedProperty>
  <ExtendedProperty>
    <ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TTSyncID" PropertyType="String"/>
    <Value>SomeStringData</Value>
  </ExtendedProperty>
```

I'm now trying to retrieve these with the other event properties through Postman calls to the MS Graph API.

From what I understand I have to use [Outlook extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and not [Open extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) to keep this backward compatible (correct me if I'm wrong).

But I can't get this to work, because the [singleValueExtendedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) expansion seems to insist on MAPIPropertyTpes and GUIDs. If I call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events/{{TTSyncedEventID}}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{{extensionID}}')
```

with `{{extensionID}} = TTSyncID` or `TTID`, I get

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
    "message": "PropertyId values may only be in one of the following formats: 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Name propertyName', 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Id propertyId' or 'MapiPropertyType propertyTag'."
  }
}
```

Can I somehow retrieve these `namespaceGuid` and use those (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273650/512728)?
Is there an easier way referencing the properties with the human-readable `TTSyncID` or `TTID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/cc9d955b-1492-47de-9dce-5bdea80a3323), namespace GUID for public strings property sets is `{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`.

If you use the following form of URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events/{{TTSyncedEventID}}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Name propertyName')
```

You should be able to get the value of `TTID` property

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events/{{TTSyncedEventID}}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Integer {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name TTID')
```

and get the value of `TTSyncID` property

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events/{{TTSyncedEventID}}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name TTSyncID')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at existing messages with these properties set with [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) (I am its author, click IMessage button to see Extended MAPI properties). In OutlookSpy you can also construct a Graph query and specify any MAPI property (fixed or named) - click Message button in the Graph group on the OutlookSpy ribbon, click "Query Parameters", check "$expand" checkbox, click on the button next to the edit box.

In your particular case, the query would most likely be

```
singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name TTSyncID')
```

[image]