# How to retrieve extended properties of type datetime?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, extended-properties

As a followup to [How to retrieve extended properties for calendar event (by name)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963189/how-to-retrieve-extended-properties-for-calendar-event-by-name/74964627#74964627): I can retrieve integer and string values with the [singleValueExtendedProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) expansion, but how to retrieve `dateTime` values?

This fails (`{{ }}` are Postman variables):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events/{{TTSyncedEventID}}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'dateTime {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name TTSyncTime')
```

...with a not very helpful response:

```json
{
  "error": {
     "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
     "message": "PropertyId values may only be in one of the following formats: 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Name propertyName', 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Id propertyId' or 'MapiPropertyType propertyTag'."
  }
}
```

I have tried several variations on `date(Time)` but without success...

Answer (score 1):

Found it thanks to Vicky's comments.
These datetime properties were created with EWS in the same manner as the integer/string values described in [the earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74963189/how-to-retrieve-extended-properties-for-calendar-event-by-name/74964627#74964627).
That code contains `PropertyType="SystemTime"`, and that is exactly what I need to use:

```xml
<typ:SetItemField>
   <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TTSyncTime" PropertyType="SystemTime"/>
   <typ:CalendarItem>
      <typ:ExtendedProperty>
         <typ:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="PublicStrings" PropertyName="TTSyncTime" PropertyType="SystemTime"/>
         <typ:Value>UTCString</typ:Value>
      </typ:ExtendedProperty>
   </typ:CalendarItem>
</typ:SetItemField>
```

So the proper query becomes:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserID}}/calendar/events/{{TTSyncedEventID}}?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'SystemTime {{PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS_NameSpace}} Name TTSyncTime')
```

(`{{ }}` are Postman variables)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0) ,there is already start/dateTime property outside of singleValueExtendedProperties , so you can directly call the API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime eq '2022-12-28T12:30:00Z' [image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this answers my question

Comment: Have you create single-value extended properties with date time?

Comment: Ah, thank you for those comments ;-) They were created with EWS in the same manner as the integer/string values as described in my earlier SO question I refer to. That code uses `PropertyType="SystemTime"`, and that is exactly what I need to use: `$filter=id eq 'SystemTime {000etc`. I'll write an anwer accordingly.

Comment: Good to hear that you are able to resolve the issue .